# How to sample from discrete 3D distribution

Tags: distributions, random-generation, java, particle-filter

I am trying to implement a particle filter to track multiple objects. During the propagation phase I need to take N samples from a three dimensional probability distribution, which does not fit known distribution types. In a 1D distribution I would just create the cumulative distribution function, invert it and take random samples from that - can I do something similar with higher dimensional distributions?

I am implementing in Java by the way, so just giving me an R function is not going to help me too much.

Comment: Does it have countably finite number of possible values for each dimension?

Comment: Yes, in fact it is limited to quite a manageable 240x180x90 cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your distribution takes form of large $I \times J \times K$ table with values mapped to probabilities

$$ \Pr(X = x, Y = y, Z = z) = p_{ijk} $$

instead of thinking of it as of a 3-dimensional object, think of it as of a table, i.e.

```
X  Y  Z  Pr
x1 y1 z1 p111
x1 y1 z2 p112
...
xI yJ zK pIJK
```

now to draw samples from it you need *only* to sample rows of such table with probabilities equal to $p_{ijk}$, so you just need an algorithm for sampling from univariate categorical distribution!

Comment: Thanks a lot, that makes a lot of sense but somehow I didn't think of it. Thanks!

Comment: @Tim Is it possible to reduce a cartesian 3d distribution to 3 histograms. Say one for $x$, where all the $y$ and $z$ value corresponding to the particular $x$ are summed over (each value of $x$ corresponds to a cumulative $y,z$ slice). The same for $y$ and $z$. Subsequently draw a sample from these 3 histograms?

Comment: @AlexanderCska I'm not sure what you mean by that by likely answer is “no”. If you want to draw samples from the joint distribution, you cannot do it by independently sampling from marginal.